# dynamic drawing in cocos2d?

Tags: drawing, cocos2d-iphone

I am working on a game which would take touch gestures as inputs. Now, i would like to display the path/gesture as the user draws it. Can someone please tell me how to do this in cocos2d?

I tried to override the draw method and used ccDrawPoint(). But the point just keeps following the touch. I guess this is because the previous drawing is getting overwritten.

Can you tell me where i am going wrong here or suggest a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution with CCRenderTexture sample test in cocos2d. Though i could not find enough documentation on it, but the sample code is enough for a start.